# Книга по Си и С++

Tags: c++, c, книги

Всем добрый день! Сегодня встолкнулся с проблемой при изучении указателей и ссылок (точнее с пониманием некоторых вещей). Но, т.к. у меня есть один знакомый, который хорошо знает Си и С++, то он помог мне в разъяснении некоторых вещей. Хотя суть вопроса не в этом.

Я задумался над тем, а какая же книга по этим языкам лучше всего будет для человека, понимающего основы и разбирающего в основе языка (циклы, условия, массивы), но желающего продолжить свое обучение и изучуть все остальное!

Скажу сразу - я занимаюсь по книге Б.Страуструпа "Язык программирования С++" (2011г.). 
Я очень много чего читал ранее про эту книгу и до сих пор не могу определить точно: подходит ли она, так сказать, для человека, который только начинает разбираться с ООП, с указателями и т.д. или все же стоит обучаться по чему-то другому?

И если не подходит, то что на ваш взгялд будет лучшим? (желательно, что бы вы указали книгу-автора-кратекое описание того, почему она лучше).

Спасибо!

Comment: Поищите по сайту, вопросов о книгах было много.

Comment: [Выборка вопросов по метке книги](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую почитать книгу Г. Шилдта - [Полный справочник по С++](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2762878). Один из лучших авторов подобных книг, всё понятно и прозрачно написано, с примерами и комментариями. Затронуты всевозможные темы - как азы, так и "продвинутые" библиотеки. ИМХО, должна быть у любого С++ разработчика.

Comment: Спасибо, качаю уже!

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал Шилдта. Он известен многочисленными ляпами и фактическими [ошибками](https://www.google.com/search?q=bullschildt).

Comment: @VladD, невозможно изложить столько информации без ошибок, ровно как и быть экспертом во всех языках. Всё же я считаю, что Шилдт - один из лучших авторов подобных книг.

Comment: минус за Шилдта. Ооочень много кто его не советует

Comment: @Roman Kotenko: Страуструпу как-то удалось изложить информацию без ошибок. Если человек не эксперт в каком-то языке (а если он не может изложить без ошибок, значит, не эксперт), зачем браться за выпуск книги?